# Does Leray spectral sequence degenerate over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two projective algebraic varieties over a field $k$ and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth projective morphism.

I have two questions:

1. Via the result of Deligne and Blanchard, we know that Leray spectral sequence degenerates over complex numbers and for the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Q}}_X$. My first question is, does this result imply that Leray's spectral sequence degenerates for all coherent sheaves?
2. Is there any condition for $X$ and $Y$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that Leray's spectral sequence degenerates for constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ ($p$ is a prime number)?

Comment: Which topology are you using?

Comment: @abx I'm using Zarisky's topology

Comment: It seems this post is confusing a lot of different things. First of all, the Deligne–Blanchard result is for the classical (analytic) topology on complex varieties, not the Zariski topology. So the analogous thing in positive characteristic would be the étale topology (with prime to $p$ coefficients). But then you also suddenly switch from the constant sheaf $\mathbf Q_X$ to *coherent* sheaves, which is totally unrelated (the constant sheaf is not coherent). Do you maybe mean locally constant (or constructible) sheaves?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Since $X$ and $Y$ are projective, I think by using GAGA, we can consider Zariski's topology to replace the analytic topology for Deligne–Blanchard theorem. I know constant sheaf is not coherent but we consider Leray spectral sequence for coherent sheaves and ask about the degeneration of this spectral sequence.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn "totally unrelated" seems to be too strong (c.f. Riemann–Hilbert correspondence in char p). Maybe "of different natures" is better.

Comment: The GAGA theorem does relate the cohomology of *coherent* sheaves for the analytic and Zariski topologies. But any constant sheaf is flabby (hence has no higher cohomology) in the Zariski topology (see Hartshorne, Exercise II.1.16(a)), which is completely different from the situation that Deligne and Blanchard describe.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn you are right. I should change my question.